# can someone explain this append() part of a for loop?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I found this code on someone else's github, and am slightly adapting it. The notebook is meant to scrape data from a website. I've passed the contents of the website through an html parser, Here's some code with the loop:

```
players = soup.find_all("td", class_ = "player")
player_list = []
for player in players[0:52]:
      player_list.append(player.a.text)
```

I just don't understand why adding the `.a.text` changes player_list compared to just having append(player) in the for loop. I can't find anything about

Example of output from just append(player):

```
<td class="player"><span style="display:none">Smith</span>
 <a href="https://www.example.com">Brian Smith</a>
 </td>,
```

Output from append(player.a.text):

```
'Brian Smith',
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `append`. `player` and `player.a.text` are two different expressions with different values.

Comment: You would need to look at the documentation for BeautifulSoup to see what type of object is returned by `find_all()` (it *isn't* a string), and what attributes (such as `a`) those objects have.

Comment: We don't want to keep the whole HTML element object.  We want to keep the text within the `<a>` tag.  You get that by using `player.a.text`.

Comment: `player.a` is the `<a>` element inside the `td`. `player.a.text` is the text content of that `<a>`

Comment: Thank you all! So it has nothing to do with append. It has to do with the objects of `players` that I'm looping through and how `find_all()` has handled those. I think I understand. Sorry if I'm not translating this well - but I think I get it. Super new to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_all` returns a list of tags. Since this returns a list, there's really no reason to append to anything else.

The dot-operator iterates through children of those tags, and `.text` accesses the non-HTML portion within the anchor (`a`) tag (plaintext).

Therefore, you get a list of Python strings. Which you could also get from

```
player_list = [player.a.text for player in soup.find_all("td", class_="player")]
first_52_players = player_list[:52]
```

Comment: As a side note, if the potential full list is HUGE, you may want to restrict its list before it is constructed: `player_list = [player.a.text for i,player in enumerate(soup.find_all("td", class_="player")) if i < 52]`

Comment: That assumes `soup.find_all` would return a lazy generator?

Comment: This list is not huge, but thank you! @OneCricketeer your new suggestion is not working after I create `soup`. I've received the following error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: `soup.find_all` would not, but having one HUGE list is better than having two :)

Comment: @ElphiusMostafa The difference between my answer and yours is that mine tries to first find all the td tags, then slices the list. Yours immediately slices. Move the `[:52]` after the find_all() to fix it, or use the enumerate option above